# How to get/log/capture the errors from a graphql apollo client query

Tags: node.js, apollo-client

I am interfacing with a graphql backend using the @apollo/client.

The request i am making returns a 400 bad request and in the network tab i can see the json of the errors.

This is what i would like to log in my code but i am uanble to.

[image]

```
        try {
            const response = await GraphQLClient.query({
                query: GET_PERSON,
                variables: {
                    personId: id,
                },
                errorPolicy: "all",
            });
            console.log("response", response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
        }
```

When i execute the above it goees into the catch block and i do not have access to the errors object.

> err Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
> at new ApolloError (index.ts:54)
> at QueryManager.ts:1073
> at both (asyncMap.ts:30)
> at asyncMap.ts:19
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.then (asyncMap.ts:19)
> at Object.error (asyncMap.ts:31)
> at notifySubscription (module.js:137)
> at onNotify (module.js:176)
> at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229)
> at iteration.ts:13
> at Array.forEach ()
> at iterateObserversSafely (iteration.ts:13)
> at Object.error (Concast.ts:185)
> at notifySubscription (module.js:137)
> at onNotify (module.js:176)
> at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229)
> at createHttpLink.ts:203

graphqlservice

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { Config } from "./../config";

const FRONTEND_API = `${Config.frontend_api}/graphql` || "";

export const GraphQLClient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: FRONTEND_API,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing console.log("err", err.message)? Also, please share your apollo configuration code as well.

Comment: err.message is simply Response not successful: Received status code 400
and not the json object

Comment: @Ammar please see updated question for apollo client config

Comment: It seems like you are getting the resolver error and Apollo is discarding the partial data from the response, which is the default behavior. Since you are using the client.query instead of useQuery hook then you need to handle these errors in the Apollo configuration using Apollo links. Please read here how you can configure your apollo with Apollo Link https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#advanced-error-handling-with-apollo-link

Comment: @Ammar hmm if what you are saying is correct and i need to handle this using apollo links im curious as to why ApolloQueryResult<T> even has the error and errors properties  export declare type ApolloQueryResult<T> = {
    data: T;
    errors?: ReadonlyArray<GraphQLError>;
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
    partial?: boolean;
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the errors as a json response in the catch method.

```
console.log(err.networkError.result.errors);
```

Still very unsure why the response object has an `error` and `errors` property and i don't know when these are accessible, maybe someone else could shed some light on that.

```
export declare type ApolloQueryResult<T> = {
    data: T;
    errors?: ReadonlyArray<GraphQLError>;
    error?: ApolloError;
    loading: boolean;
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
    partial?: boolean;
};
```